# Selecting first record for each FK provided in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

To make things a bit simpler I have created a hypothetical scenario around my actual problem. Take the following schema for example:
[image]

Let's say I am wanting to do all of the following in order, in one query

1. Order all audit records by `DateUpdated` DESC
2. `SELECT` only the first record (so as to get the most recent audit)
3. (Here is the catch) select the first record for each `ClientId` supplied

This is pretty simple if I were trying to get the first record for a single client. Then it would simply be something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id, ClientId, Data, DateUpdated
FROM AuditRecord
WHERE ClientId = xxx
ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC
```

However, my where clause is actually going to be an `IN` statement

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id, ClientId, Data, DateUpdated 
FROM AuditRecord 
WHERE ClientId IN (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)
ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC
```

How can I select the first (most recent) record for each client id supplied in my IN clause without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @APH pointed out, you can make used of window functions, but this is a perfect application for a cross/outer apply operation as well:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.ClientId, t.Data, t.DateUpdated 
FROM AuditRecord t
cross apply (
        select top 1 c.Id
        from AuditRecord c
        where c.ClientId = t.ClientId
        order by c.DateUpdated desc
    )
WHERE t.ClientId IN (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)
```

You'd have to test in your environment to see which makes more sense/is more efficient, but in most scenarios, an APPLY operation will outperform a window function used for this same scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using a partition and subquery.  `Row_number` will assign sequential integers to each row, starting with the highest `DateUpdated`, and starting over at 1 for each new `ClientID`.  You could also do this with a CTE or temp table if you prefer.

```
Select Id, ClientId, Data, DateUpdated from 
    (SELECT Id, ClientId, Data, DateUpdated
    , row_number() over (partition by ClientID Order by DateUpdated Desc) as RN 
    FROM AuditRecord WHERE ClientId IN (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)) a
where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `SELECT MAX(DateUpdated), ClientId from AuditRecord Group by ClientID` will give you the latest DateUpdated for each ClientID.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you every client record with it's most recent audit data field (or nulls if none exist).

```
select * 
from Client
outer apply
    (
    select top 1 AuditRecord.*
    from AuditRecord 
    where AuditRecord.ClientID = Client.ID
    order by DateUpdated desc
    ) TopAuditRecord
```